# aws_resource_tag resource - must supply a name

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

I'm attempting to create a recipe to tag aws instances. I'm using the attribute below:

```
node.default['aws-tag'] = [
    {
        :awsid => node['ec2']['instance_id'],
        :key => 'TagKey',
        :value => 'TagValue'
    }
]
```

Here's the code that is supposed to assign the tag to the instance id:

```
node['aws-tag'].each do |tag|
  aws_resource_tag tag['awsid'] do
    tags(
        tag['key'] => tag['value']
    )
  end
end
```

What I'm expecting to happen, in this case, is the instance should get tagged with TagKey and TagValue. However, I get the error "You must supply a name when declaring a aws_resource_tag resource" on line 11.

```
   10:  node['aws-tag'].each do |tag|
   11>>   aws_resource_tag tag['awsid'] do
   12:      tags(
   13:          tag['key'] => tag['value']
   14:      )
   15:    end
   16:  end
   17:
```

Am I right in thinking that

> aws_resource_tag tag['awsid'] do

should be no different than

> aws_resource_tag node['ec2']['instance_id'] do

I've verified that entering **aws_resource_tag node['ec2']['instance_id'] do** into my code works. Anyone know why **aws_resource_tag tag['awsid'] do** doesn't work?

Comment: This may be a ruby issue, because you're mixing symbols (in the assignment) and strings (in the resource creation).  Try `tag[:awsid]` as the `aws_resource_tag` name.

Comment: The error is here :awsid => node['ec2']['instance_id'] You cannot define attribute in this way in ruby

Comment: Actually, you can define hashes that way in ruby.  (Try it!)  It's the old "hash-rocket" style, but it still works in ruby 2+.

Comment: Thanks, Karen! Your first comment solved the problem.

Also, I attempted to try the "new" style, but couldn't get it to work. Sticking with hash-rockets for now.